# Using custom decorators with Slack Bolt Python SDK

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack, python-decorators

Is it possible to use my own python decorators with the Bolt SDK?

I tried the code below, and it's not working:

```
@it_platform
@app.command("/help")
def action_help():
    # * Log to Cloudwatch
    logging.info("The user triggered the command /help")
```

I'm getting the error `Unhandled request ({'type': None, 'command': '/help'})`

If i remove the decorator `@it_platform` it works fine.

I also tried putting the decorator `@it_platform` below the Bolt decorator, but it gives the same error message.

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which `slack-sdk` version are you using ?

With the latest sdk version [1.14.3](https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-python/releases/tag/v1.14.3) they've fixed the kwargs issue with custom decorators.

Maybe you are using an old version